# How do I find icon path for AppImage file?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, antergos

I installed Hyper terminal (hyper.is) by downloading the `.AppImage` file and moving it to `/usr/bin/`. It doesn't show up in Gnome's launcher though, so I manually created a `.desktop` file for it. That worked, but the only issue is that the icon isn't displaying. I don't know which path to put in the Icon parameter.

How can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a known appimaged issue, https://github.com/probonopd/AppImageKit/issues/328. Any help appreciated.